How to kill threading and FASTAPI with Ctrl+C?
I would like to stop the execution of a process and FASTAPI with Ctrl+C in Python. But I recieving error KeyboardInterrupt exceptions, how to properly stop threads and FAST API
from fastapi import FastAPI
import threading
import time
import signal
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from model import core
from model.database import engine, SessionLocal, get_db
from model.core import Timestamp
from routers.timestamps import router as timestamps_router

core.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(router=timestamps_router)

def record_timestamp():
    while True:
        db = SessionLocal()
        new_timestamp = Timestamp(timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
        db.add(new_timestamp)
        db.commit()
        db.close()
        time.sleep(5)


def delete_old_timestamps():
    while True:
        db = SessionLocal()
        one_minute_ago = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=1)
        db.query(Timestamp).filter(Timestamp.timestamp < one_minute_ago).delete()
        db.commit()
        db.close()
        time.sleep(10)


@app.on_event("startup")
def startup_event():
    get_db()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=record_timestamp)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=delete_old_timestamps)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()


i triend to wite a signal with ChatGPT but also had failed

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Just how you you define a startup event, you can define a shutdown event like this:
from fastapi import FastAPI
import threading
import time
import signal
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from model import core
from model.database import engine, SessionLocal, get_db
from model.core import Timestamp
from routers.timestamps import router as timestamps_router

core.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router=timestamps_router)

stop_event = threading.Event()

def record_timestamp():
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        db = SessionLocal()
        new_timestamp = Timestamp(timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
        db.add(new_timestamp)
        db.commit()
        db.close()
        stop_event.wait(5)

def delete_old_timestamps():
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        db = SessionLocal()
        one_minute_ago = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=1)
        db.query(Timestamp).filter(Timestamp.timestamp < one_minute_ago).delete()
        db.commit()
        db.close()
        stop_event.wait(10)

@app.on_event("startup")
def startup_event():
    get_db()
    global t1, t2
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=record_timestamp)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=delete_old_timestamps)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

@app.on_event("shutdown")
def shutdown_event():
    stop_event.set()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

def handle_exit(signal, frame):
    shutdown_event()
    
    import sys
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_exit)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_exit)

